# Is there a reciprocal agreement between US and UK for credit on social security taxes?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom

I am a UK citizen living and working in the US. When I return to the UK can I get a credit for the social security taxes I paid over many years in the US - in other words does reciprocity exist on social security (FICA) taxes paid between the US and the UK?

Comment: Seems to be yes. http://www.ssa.gov/international/Agreement_Pamphlets/uk.html

Answer (score 3):

There's such an agreement. It is called "Totalization Agreement", you can find all about it [on the SSA web site](http://www.ssa.gov/international/Agreement_Pamphlets/uk.html).

You'll have to read through it and talk to a licensed tax adviser in the UK to know exactly what it entitles you to.